# RegEx to match ends with

Tags: java, regex

I need to write regex in java to match domain and subdomain(.domain.com).
Regex should return true for

```
domain.com
m.domain.com
abc.domain.com
www.domain.com
```

but returns false for

```
abcdomain.com
1domain.com
```

I try to match domain.com and and if preceding character is present then it must be .

I tried various options but it is failing in one or other test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^|.*?\.)domain\.com
```

Try this. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lB2sH2/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(\.|^)domain.com$
```

The first part means that there should be a . or nothing
and the $ means, "ends with"

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
(^|\.)domain\.com$
```

but Java mostly handles only full-line matches, so:

```
(.+\.)?domain\.com
```

or you can use the .endWith() method in Java code:

```
if (domain.equals("domain.com") || domain.endsWith(".domain.com")) {
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?:\\w+\\.?)?domain\\.com
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pO1rD6/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
\bdomain\.com$
```

http://rubular.com/r/QG0FtVWtm6

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what "domain.com" is going to be, this regex below should give you just the subdomain of whatever domain you are looking for. Matches your specifications, including domains that look like `abc.net`

```
([a-z]+)(?=\.[a-z]+\.)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oI3rI3/3)